# How to use different authentication modes for same application

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

I am developing a web application in asp.net(C#).The root folder contains pages specific to main website and a sub folder 'Admin' contains files of admin panel.

I want to give specific pages in `loginUrl` and `defaultUrl` for **Admin panel**.

Is there any way to use `authentication` tag with `mode="Forms"` in another **Web.config** inside **Admin** folder..

Any help would be appreciated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way of doing what you need via the `web.config` file that's built-in as the `forms` element can only be defined at application-level. However, that's not to say it can't be done.

You could have a custom handler which re-directs you to the appropriate login URL and store the configuration for that in the `web.config`.

Comment: Thanks...I am doing the same but i just thought if there is a way of doing it using predefined `authentication`..You have cleared my confusion..

Answer (score 0):

You can add your page to a folder and you can protect this folder by adding a new `web.config` file

for example ,

```
-YourRoolFolder  
    -AdminFolder  
      -yourPage.aspx  
      -web.config
```

in new `web.config` file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><configuration>  
<system.web>
    <authorization>
        <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
</system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: It will redirect me to the login page of root..I want to redirect to the login page inside the admin folder..

Comment: what about using `loginView` ?

Comment: I haven't use `loginView` before.May be it work but i wanted to use it through **FormAuthentication**.